# abp framework - change app name , remove lepton logo

Tags: c#, .net, abp

im running the abp framework with blazor server,
When i created the project i named it workProj, i want to rename it now
For some reason after i've added this class as the documentation states:

```
  [Dependency(ReplaceServices = true)]
        public class ProjectBrandingProvider : DefaultBrandingProvider
        {
            public override string AppName => "KTT Recruitment";
        }
    }
```

Nothing happens, name stays the same, do i need to invoke this somewhere somehow?

In addition how would i go about changing the lepton logo? there is no images folder in the wwroot.

Edit:
This does work:
@using Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Components.Web.LeptonXLiteTheme.Themes.LeptonXLite;
@using Volo.Abp.DependencyInjection

```
@inherits Branding
@attribute 
[ExposeServices(typeof(Branding))]
@attribute [Dependency(ReplaceServices = 
true)]
@name
@code{
    string name = "Ktt Recruitment";
}
```

Howerver, why wont the proper methode work? whats going on exactly?

Answer (score 2):

You can change the leptonx logo in the following ways:

1-) Virtual File System: You can override the branding component and add a new logo. If you only want to change the logo and app-name, I think you don't need to override the component completely. Because then you will not get any updates further on.

2-) Branding Provider Class: You can override the `AppName`, `LogoUrl` and `LogoReverseUrl` properties. (build and re-run the application required)

3-) Global CSS File *(I think the easiest way)*: You can open the `global-styles.css` file under the *wwwroot* folder and update the related part (https://github.com/abpframework/abp/blob/dev/templates/app/aspnet-core/src/MyCompanyName.MyProjectName.Blazor.Server/wwwroot/global-styles.css#L6-L9):

```css
:root .lpx-brand-logo {
    --lpx-logo: url('<your-logo-path-ex:/images/my-logo.png>');
    --lpx-logo-icon: url('<your-logo-path-ex:/images/my-logo-icon.png>');
}
```

---

Please check [this documentation](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Themes/LeptonXLite/Blazor?UI=BlazorServer#components) for more info.